# Why can't map::find a pointer to a const?

Tags: c++, stl

briefly, why does it not compile

```
#include <map>
int main()
{
    std::map<int*, char> m;
    const int *x = nullptr;
    m.find(x);
}
```

What could possibly be the reason for that not to be a valid piece of code?

Why does it matter to `find` whether it's a pointer or a pointer to a const??

Looks and smells like a bug...

And no thanks, no `const_cast`

Comment: FWIW You really shouldn't use a pointer as the key of an associative container.

Comment: Do you expect a function that expects an `int *` to be able to accept a `const int *`?

Comment: @NathanOliver why? `std::less` is guaranteed to give us total ordering for pointers.

Comment: @jxh that's the thing, it shouldn't expect something mutable, it only needs to read the variable, nothing more! This is simply common sense...

Comment: It will accept a `int * const`. But a `const int *` is different

Comment: @PustoPusto it's not a bug, but an oversight in C++ prior to C++14.

Comment: @jxh but it doesn't matter... As I said, there's really no logical reason for this not to work

Comment: @SergeyA how does an oversight differ from a bug? really

Comment: A custom comparator might want to modify the key.

Comment: I think @NathanOliver's point is why are you using a pointer for a key? It just doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @SergeyA I'm not saying it will be a problem, it just normally people thing it will sort on what it is pointing at, no the address held by the pointer.  For a lot of new programmers it causes a lot of mistakes.

Comment: @PustoPusto You can call it a bug if you want. Regardless, it got fixed in C++14.

Comment: "Looks and smells like a bug..."  It is definitely a bug in the code.

Comment: @SergeyA how? https://wandbox.org/permlink/xy30CoMI5dypCLtP

Comment: @NathanOliver I can think of a case or two where the actual address of an object would be used to verify object equality. It is some special case, no questions.

Comment: @PustoPusto how what? You have two answers below which show how to achieve your goals. Also, I think you might want to change your attitude. Your last comment was way out of line.

Answer (score 3):

> Looks and smells like a bug...

Why would it be a bug?

The parameter of `find` is a const reference to the key type (const reference to `int *`).

You can't bind `const int *` to such a reference, since `const int *` can't be implicitly converted to `int *`.

---

Since C++14 you could fix that by using a transparent comparator: `std::map<int*, char, std::less<>>`.

With a transparent comaprator `find` becomes a template. It will work with any parameter type, as long as it can be compared with the key type.

Answer (score 2):

The default version of `std::map<int*, char>` uses `less<int*>` as comparator, which, in turn, has function `()(const int*, const int*)` defined in it.

This function will not accept `int*`

However, if you use `less<>`, it will work:

```
std::map<int*, char, std::less<>> m;
```

The reason for that is that `std::less<void>` defines a template function,

```
template< class T, class U>
constexpr auto operator()( T&& lhs, U&& rhs ) const
```

And this works just fine when compares const vs non-const pointers.

Comment: Ninja'd by 4 seconds. :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat let's resolve our differences with shooting contest and see how can draw their Smith & Wesson faster? :P Also, where do you see timestamp with one second precision?

Comment: @SergeyA, Just hover over the timestamp.  Works that way in Chrome on a Windows laptop, at least.